# How to fix bad URI(is not URI? in ruby on rails, passing variables as parameters in URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

URI that fetches weather report of Kentucky(KY) state and "murray" city(apikey replaced)

http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/conditions/q/KY/murray.json

I want to take inputs of state(Eg:KY) and city using input boxes and pass them as variables to the URI so that i can make the page dynamic to the user's choice, So tried to modify the URI to :

http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/conditions/q/#{state}/#{city}.json

I am unable to pass variables as parameters to this api URI and getting error

"bad URI(is not URI?):

my weather.erb file contents(partial code):

```
<% provide(:title, "Weather") %>
<h1>Weather Forecast</h1>
  <%=form_tag  do%>
  <%=label_tag 'Enter State (Eg:KY)'%>
  <%=text_field_tag 'state'%><br>
  <%=label_tag 'Enter City (Eg:Murray)'%>
  <%=text_field_tag 'city'%><br>
  <%=submit_tag 'submit '%>
  <%end%>


<% 
city = yield(:city).strip
state = yield(:state).strip
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
open('http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/conditions/q/#{state}/#{city}.json') do |f|
..........
........
.....
%>
```

I am done with modifying routes, application_controller and stuck with this.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
'http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/conditions/q/#{state}/#{city}.json'
```

to

```
"http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/conditions/q/#{state}/#{city}.json"
```

Since single quotes do not interpolate variables.